# .cfm file displayed as raw code

Tags: parsing, browser, coldfusion

i have a .cfm file on my website
but when i open it in a browser it is displayed as a raw code instead of parsing
can anyone help ?

I am using a remotely hosted webserver

Comment: We need a lot more information to answer this question:
1. What kind of server are you using?
2. Have you installed ColdFusion on the server?
3. When you installed CF, did you install it as a StandAlone or using JRun?

Give us more information, and I'm sure we can make it work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you have installed CF in window2008r2? If so, CF cannot completely installed and configured ISAPI at back-end.

We need to install or turn on for ISAPI extensions and ISAPI filters as follow.

**Administrative Tools > Server Manager**

Server Manager Box will come out (screen-1). If ISAPI extensions and ISAPI filters are not installed under Web Server (IIS), we need to click Add Roles Services at the right side.

[image: please check this screen]

Once we’ve done clicking on Add Roles Services, Add Roles Services box will come out (Screen-2) and you will see ISAPI extensions and ISAPI filters are uncheck as not installed (In Screen-16, they both are checked as installed because of we’ve encountered this problem and which are installed already) under Application Development. To click on ISAPI extensions and ISAPI filters and click on install button. We need to restart IIS if necessary.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your server supports ColdFusion and that it's enabled, and that the web server configuration is set to pass files with the `.cfm` suffix to its handler.

Comment: I am a newbie and i don't know how to check whether the server supports cold fusion
can you let me know how ?

Comment: Are you using a hosting company?  I would ask them.  If its not working, however, I doubt its supported, and if it is, it may be turned off.